# How to determine whether a year is a leap year?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple calculator to determine whether or not a certain year is a leap year.

By definition, a leap year is divisible by four, but not by one hundred, unless it is divisible by four hundred.

Here is my code:

```
def leapyr(n):
    if n%4==0 and n%100!=0:
        if n%400==0:
            print(n, "is a leap year.")
    elif n%4!=0:
        print(n, "is not a leap year.")
print(leapyr(1900))
```

When I try this inside the Python IDLE, the module returns `None`. I am pretty sure that I should get `1900 is a leap year`.

Comment: 1900 is not a leap year. But 2000 is. Also 2000 and 1900 are both divisible by 100, so you will never get 2000 as a positive hit.

Comment: Even alleged experts can get this wrong: see [Excel incorrectly assumes that the year 1900 is a leap year](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214326/excel-incorrectly-assumes-that-the-year-1900-is-a-leap-year).

Comment: @PM2Ring the link you provided gives a very good explanation why Excel gets it wrong. It was not that they didn't know better, they did it for compatibility reasons. It was deliberate. For more background see https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/

Comment: Note that your function doesn't return anything, so trying to `print` the result will *always* print `None`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sure, Excel is merely retaining compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3. I didn't claim that the Excel authors were ignorant of the correct leap year rules, I just copied the title of that Microsoft article.

Comment: @PM2Ring I only mentioned it because your wording implied they made a mistake rather than a deliberate choice. "Alleged experts can get this wrong" is a pretty strong statement.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, it is a strong statement, but I assumed the interested reader would click the link and read the details. Thanks for the link to the article by Joel. *"If you ignore 1900, you can figure out if a given year is a leap year just by looking to see if the rightmost two bits are zero. That’s really fast and easy. The Lotus guys probably figured it didn’t matter to be wrong for those two months way in the past."* Ok, maybe it was a deliberate shortcut, not an ignorant mistake. But I guess we need docs about Lotus development to find out.

Comment: @PM2Ring I don't remember if Joel's post mentions it, but there was a good reason for Lotus to take that shortcut too. They were working with memory constraints that simply don't exist today. I think that even with all that, 1-2-3 and Excel will disagree about whether 2100 is a leap year or not. I hope nobody alive today will ever need to worry about it.

Comment: @MarkRansom Oh, memory constraints are a valid reason. FWIW, my early coding experiences were on [one of these machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360_Model_20), so I know all about memory constraints. ;)

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Use [`calendar.isleap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.isleap):

```
import calendar
print(calendar.isleap(1900))
```

Answer (score 73):

As a one-liner function:

```
def is_leap_year(year):
    """Determine whether a year is a leap year."""

    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)
```

It's similar to the [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622506/244297), but short circuits at the first test (note the parenthesis).

Alternatively, you can use the standard library's [`calendar.isleap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.isleap), which has exactly the same [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/calendar.py#L100):

```
from calendar import isleap
print(isleap(1900))  # False
```

Answer (score 23):

You test three different things on n:

```
n % 4
n % 100
n % 400
```

For 1900:

```
1900 % 4 == 0
1900 % 100 == 0
1900 % 400 == 300
```

So 1900 doesn't enter the `if` clause because `1900 % 100 != 0` is `False`

But 1900 also doesn't enter the `else` clause because `1900 % 4 != 0` is also `False`

This means that execution reaches the end of your function and doesn't see a return statement, so it returns `None`.

This rewriting of your function should work, and should return `False` or `True` as appropriate for the year number you pass into it.  (Note that, as in the other answer, you have to return something rather than print it.)

```
def leapyr(n):
    if n % 400 == 0:
        return True
    if n % 100 == 0:
        return False
    if n % 4 == 0:
        return True
    return False
print leapyr(1900)
```

(Algorithm from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year))

Comment: +1 for identifying logic errors. Still, the OP's code does not contain a `return` statement. Fixing the errors that you've pointed out here will not help with that.

Answer (score 12):

The whole formula can be contained in a single expression:

```
def is_leap_year(year):
    return (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or year % 400 == 0

print n, " is a leap year" if is_leap_year(n) else " is not a leap year"
```

Comment: This formula is certainly correct, but Eugene's version is equally readable but with better short-circuiting. OTOH, I doubt that micro-optimization at this level would be noticeable in most real-world code. :) Calling `calendar.isleap` is far more readable, although undoubtedly slower, due to the overhead of Python function calls.

Comment: @PM2Ring I don't disagree, and I'm happy to note that both answers are much higher voted than mine at this time. I do think that my grouping is more in the spirit of the leap year rules, even if another arrangement is a tiny bit more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Your function doesn't return anything, so that's why when you use it with the `print` statement you get `None`. So either just call your function like this:

```
leapyr(1900)
```

or modify your function to return a value (by using the `return` statement), which then would be printed by your `print` statement.

***Note*: This does not address any possible problems you have with your leap year computation, but ANSWERS YOUR SPECIFIC QUESTION** as to *why* you are getting `None` as a result of your function call in conjunction with your `print`.

*Explanation*:

Some short examples regarding the above:

```
def add2(n1, n2):
    print 'the result is:', n1 + n2  # prints but uses no *return* statement

def add2_New(n1, n2):
    return n1 + n2    # returns the result to caller
```

Now when I call them:

```
print add2(10, 5)
```

this gives:

```
the result is: 15
None
```

The first line comes form the `print` statement *inside* of `add2()`. The `None` from the print statement when I call the function `add2()` which does **not** have a return statement, causing the `None` to be printed. Incidentally, if I had just called the  `add2()` function simply with (note, ***no*** `print` statement):

```
add2()
```

I would have just gotten the output of the print statement `the result is: 15` without the `None` (which looks like what you are trying to do).

Compare this with:

```
print add2_New(10, 5)
```

which gives:

```
15
```

In this case the result is computed in the function `add2_New()` and no print statement, and returned to the caller who then prints it in turn.

Comment: It might help to clarify that `print`ing does not return a value. The OP must explicitly call `return` in order to actually return a value

Comment: @inspectorG4dget good point, I just added mention of the `return` statement, I'll see if I can clarify this further. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think adding a return statement will solve the problem. The code provided by OP is wrong as pointed in the other answer. You didn't fix the logical errors (and OP doesn't need a return code. He just prints the information!)

Comment: @JBernardo My answer explains why OP is getting `None` .. calling a function without return with a `print` statement will print `None`. I am not fixing her leap year code.

Comment: The return statement is not OP's problem if you haven't realized. He just want to get printed if `x` is or not a leap year.

Comment: @JBernardo the *lack* of the return statement is what is causing the `None`. If you doubt this, put in a `return 'apple'` and you won't get `None`. As I said above, my answer explains and deals with this, not the computation.

Comment: @Levon Yeah, I remember :) I'm not downvoting you though but this time your answer will not solve the part of the question that says `"I am pretty sure that I should get 1900 is a leap year"`

Comment: More directorly... 1900 is not a leap year. I suggest you check your definition of how leap years are calculated.

Comment: @Carl You probably want to direct your comment at OP above, right below their post. I'm not computing or presenting an algorithm for determining a leap year, so your suggestion is misdirected.

Answer (score 2):

A leap year is exactly divisible by 4 except for century years (years ending with 00). The century year is a leap year only if it is perfectly divisible by 400. For example,

```
if( (year % 4) == 0):
    if ( (year % 100 ) == 0):

        if ( (year % 400) == 0):

            print("{0} is a leap year".format(year))
        else:

            print("{0} is not a leap year".format(year))
    else:

        print("{0} is a leap year".format(year))

else:

    print("{0} is not a leap year".format(year))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to `import calendar` and apply `.isleap` method you can try this:

```
def isleapyear(year):
    if year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0):
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: You could just return the result of the statement, as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30714165/275088).

Answer (score 0):

In the Gregorian calendar, three conditions are used to identify leap years:

- The year can be evenly divided by 4, is a leap year, unless:

  - The year can be evenly divided by 100, it is NOT a leap year, unless:

    - The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.

This means that in the Gregorian calendar, the years 2000 and 2400 are leap years, while 1800, 1900, 2100, 2200, 2300 and 2500 are NOT leap years. [source](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html)

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    if year % 4 == 0:
        leap = True
        if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 == 0:
            leap = False
            if year % 400 == 0:
                leap = True 
    return leap

year = int(input())
leap = is_leap(year)

if leap:
  print(f"{year} is a leap year")
else:
  print(f"{year} is not a leap year")
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic in the "one-liner" works fine.  From personal experience, what has helped me is to assign the statements to variables (in their "True" form) and then use logical operators for the result:

```
A = year % 4 == 0
B = year % 100 == 0
C = year % 400 == 0
```

I used '==' in the B statement instead of "!=" and applied 'not' logical operator in the calculation:

```
leap = A and (not B or C)
```

This comes in handy with a larger set of conditions, and to simplify the boolean operation where applicable before writing a whole bunch of if statements.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative one liner:

`((((y % 4) + (int((y - (y % 100)) / y) * ((y % 400) / 100))) - 1) < 0)`

This was something that I put together for fun (?) that is also 1:1 compatible with C.

`(y % 4)` >>>It first checks if the year is a leap year via the typical mod-4 check.

`(int((y - (y % 100)) / y)` >>>It then accounts for those years divisible by 100. If the year is evenly divisible by 100, this will result in a value of 1, otherwise it will result in a value of 0.

`((y % 400) / 100)))` >>>Next, the year is divided by 400 (and subsequently 100, to return 1, 2, or 3 if it is not.

These two values

`(int(y - (y % 100)) / y)`

&

`((y % 400) / 100)))`

are then multiplied together. If the year is not divisible by 100, this will always equal 0, otherwise if it is divisible by 100, but not by 400, it will result in 1, 2, or 3. If it is divisible by both 100 and 400, it will result in 0.

This value is added to `(y % 4)`, which will only be equal to 0 if the year is a leap year after accounting for the edge-cases.

Finally, 1 is subtracted from this remaining value, resulting in -1 if the year is a leap year, and either 0, 1, or 2 if it is not. This value is compared against 0 with the less-than operator. If the year is a leap year this will result in True (or 1, if used in C), otherwise it will return False (or 0, if used in C).

Please note: this code is horribly inefficient, incredibly unreadable, and a detriment to any code attempting to follow proper practices. This was an exercise of mine to see if I could do so, and nothing more.

Further, be aware that ZeroDivisionErrors are a consequence of the input year equaling 0, and must be accounted for.

For example, a VERY basic timeit comparison of 1000 executions shows that, when compared against an equivalent codeblock utilizing simple if-statements and the modulus operator, this one-liner is roughly 5 times slower than its if-block equivalent.

That being said, I do find it highly entertaining!

Answer (score 0):

The missing part is the use of return statement:

```
def is_year_leap(year):
    if year % 100 == 0:
        if year %  400 == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    elif year % 4 == 0:
        return True

    else:
        return False

x = is_year_leap(int(input('Enter any year: ')))
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried solving in this way and it as work for me like a charm !!!

**Logic I applied to find leap year or not**

```
print([ (1900 % 4 == 0 ) , (1900 % 400 == 0) , (1900 % 100 == 0) ] )
print([ (2022 % 4 == 0 ) , (2022 % 400 == 0) , (2022 % 100 == 0) ] )
print([ (2000 % 4 == 0 ) , (2000 % 400 == 0) , (2000 % 100 == 0) ] )
print([ (1896 % 4 == 0 ) , (1896 % 400 == 0) , (1896 % 100 == 0) ] )
print([ (2020 % 4 == 0 ) , (2020 % 400 == 0) , (2020 % 100 == 0) ] )
```

**Output :**

```
[True, False, True]
[False, False, False]
[True, True, True]
[True, False, False]
[True, False, False]
```

**My code :**

```
yy = 2100

lst = [ (yy % 4  == 0)   , (yy % 400 == 0) , (yy % 100 == 0)  ]

if lst.count(True) in [0,2]:
  print('Not Leap Year')
else:
  print('Leap Year')
```

**Output :**

```
Not Leap Year
```

**Incase you find any issue in my code feel free to guide me**

Answer (score 0):

Call me old-fashioned, but I'd just ask if February 29 of the year you're interested in is a valid date:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('29022025', '%d%m%Y').date()
```

^ returns a ValueError, because Feb 29, 2025 is not a date.

Answer (score -1):

From 1700 to 1917, official calendar was the Julian calendar. Since then they we use the Gregorian calendar system. The transition from the Julian to Gregorian calendar system occurred in 1918, when the next day after January 31st was February 14th. This means that 32nd day in 1918, was the February 14th.

In both calendar systems, February is the only month with a variable amount of days, it has 29 days during a leap year, and 28 days during all other years. In the Julian calendar, leap years are divisible by 4 while in the Gregorian calendar, leap years are either of the following:

Divisible by 400.

Divisible by 4 and not divisible by 100.

So the program for leap year will be:

```
def leap_notleap(year):

    yr = ''
    if year <= 1917:
        if year % 4 == 0:
            yr = 'leap'
        else:
            yr = 'not leap'
    elif year >= 1919:
        if (year % 400 == 0) or (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0):
            yr = 'leap'
        else:
            yr = 'not leap'
    else:
        yr = 'none actually, since feb had only 14 days'

    return yr
```

Comment: The adoption of the Gregorian calendar happened in 1918 in the Soviet Union. Most other countries which use the Gregorian calendar adopted it much earlier, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adoption_dates_of_the_Gregorian_calendar_per_country