# Python: Determining the Leap Year

Tags: python

I have to write a program where I enter a number and the program replies whether the number is a leap year or not. I'm new to python so I am unsure of where to start. So far, I know that a leap year is any number divisible by `4`, but not by `100` (unless it is also divisible by 400).

Comment: Watch some introductory Python, and get yourself started.

Comment: DO the same in python check it if it is divisible and other

Comment: Go through http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/ and take some strong basics ..

Comment: If you are so lazy then check it - http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/leap-year

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I'm reviewing the basics as we speak, just needed a way to good strategy to start thinking about the problem since I'm new.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine whether a year is a leap year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621740/how-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year)

Comment: I am mystified that this very natural question received at least 3 downvotes (I upvoted it from -3 to -2).

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in `calendar.isleap`:

```py
import calendar

calendar.isleap(2020)
#=> True
```

Comment: Please, please, please ... don't put the first letter of **every** word in uppercase - it makes it very hard to read.

Comment: I have changed all the text to sentence case.

Answer (score 0):

I am also a python beginner. I tried my best, see if this works.

```
def isLeap(year):
    tyear = year
    if tyear % 4 == 0:
        tyear = year
        if tyear % 100 == 0:
            tyear = year
            if tyear % 400 == 0:
                print('Leap Year')
            else:
                print('Not a Leap Year')
        else:
            print('Leap Year')
    else:
        print('Not a Leap Year')

isLeap(2004) # Returns Leap Year
isLeap(2005) # Returns Not a Leap Year
```

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe this could help.

```
year = int(input("Input year: "))

if year % 4 == 0:
    print("Year is leap.")
    if year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0:
        print("Year is common.")

else:
    print("Year is common.")
```

Answer (score -1):

Most previous answers are correct here is another way to skin a cat:

The math logic is based on this [full credit](https://www.kumon.com/resources/leap-year-math/#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%20Gregorian%20Calendar,year%20is%20divisible%20by%20400.)

```
year = 2024
if year % 4 != 0:
    return False
elif year % 100 != 0:
    return True
elif year % 400 != 0:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Here is test case

```
def checkit(year):
    if year % 4 != 0:
        return False
    elif year % 100 != 0:
        return True
    elif year % 400 != 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

x = range(2013,2027)
for n in x:    
    print(n,checkit(n))
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how to do leap years :)

```
if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0:
print(year, "is leap!")
```

else:
print(year, "is not leap!")