# Whey is_leap_year returning None instead of True

Tags: python

Why does this code print None instead of True. It seems that once it checks if it divisible by 4 it does not go on to check the other requirements. From my current understanding, for each successive if statement it should keep going down and checking the next if until one of them is false. At which point it should go the the else statement and return False. But, obviously I'm doing something wrong. Thank you.

```
def is_leap_year(year):
        # step 1 check if dvisible by 4
        if year % 4 == 0:
            print "year is divisble by 4"
            # step 2 check if divisible by 100
            if year % 100 == 0:
                print "year is divisible by 100"
                # step 3 check if divisble by 400
                if year % 400 == 0:
                    print "year is divisible by 400"
                    return True
        else:
            return False

print is_leap_year(1996)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else` refers only to the first `if` - i.e. for years not divisible by four. Therefore for a year divisible by four, but not by 100 you do not fall into the `else`. Python functions return `None` if no return value is specified.

In general `else` refers to the last `if` with the same indentation.

You can fix it by doing:

```
def is_leap_year(year):
# step 1 check if dvisible by 4
if year % 4 == 0:
    print "year is divisble by 4"
    # step 2 check if divisible by 100
    if year % 100 == 0:
        print "year is divisible by 100"
        # step 3 check if divisble by 400
        if year % 400 == 0:
            print "year is divisible by 400"
            return True
    else:
        return True
return False
```

Comment: Thanks Henry. I also recognized a flaw in my algorithm that determines whether or not it is a leap year. For example it should be testing for not divisible by 100 and not divisible by 400.

Answer (score 1):

> From my current understanding, for each successive if statement it
>   should keep going down and checking the next if until one of them is
>   false. At which point it should go the the else statement and return
>   False

No that isn't completely true. That `else` block is only executed when the first `if` block is not i.e when the year is not divisible by 4. When the other `if` blocks are not (e.g for a year divisible by 4 and not by 100), the function will rightly *return* `None`.

Instead, you can `return False` in the case everything other `if` fails:

```
def is_leap_year(year):
        # step 1 check if dvisible by 4
        if year % 4 == 0:
            print "year is divisble by 4"
            # step 2 check if divisible by 100
            if year % 100 == 0:
                print "year is divisible by 100"
                # step 3 check if divisble by 400
                if year % 400 == 0:
                    print "year is divisible by 400"
                    return True
        return False
```

That said, I'm not sure about the correctness of your approach. Here is an SO post that can help you improve your code:

[How to determine whether a year is a leap year in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621740/how-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year-in-python)

---

Otherwise, you may find out if a year is leap using [`calendar.isleap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.isleap):

```
import calendar

print(calendar.isleap(2000))
```

Comment: @JeffRSon Yes, I left a link they could use to improve the logic of their code. Thank you for noting.

Answer (score 1):

Your function will only return `True` if the year is divisible by `4`, `100` *and* `400` and it will return `False` if the year is not divisible by `4`.

There are a number of cases where you haven't specified the return value (e.g. divisible by `4` but *not* divisible by `100`).  In those cases, your function will return `None`.  `1996` falls into those cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach:

```
def is_leap_year(year):
    leap = False

    # step 1 check if dvisible by 4
    if year % 4 == 0:
        print "year is divisble by 4"
        leap = True

    # step 2 check if divisible by 100
    if year % 100 == 0:
        print "year is divisible by 100"
        leap = False

    # step 3 check if divisble by 400
    if year % 400 == 0:
        print "year is divisible by 400"
        leap = True

    return leap    
print is_leap_year(1996)
```

Explanation: year is leap if it is dividable by 4, and not leap if is dividable by 100 (unless it is also dividable by 400).