# Determining leap years

Tags: python, function, if-statement, testing, nested

We know it's a leap year if it's divisible by four and, if it's a century year,  it's divisible by 400. I thought I would need two If Statements like this:

```
def isLeap(n):

if n % 100 == 0 and n % 400 == 0:
    return True
if n % 4 == 0:
    return True
else:
    return False

# Below is a set of tests so you can check if the code is correct.

from test import testEqual

testEqual(isLeap(1944), True)
testEqual(isLeap(2011), False)
testEqual(isLeap(1986), False)
testEqual(isLeap(1956), True)
testEqual(isLeap(1957), False)
testEqual(isLeap(1800), False)
testEqual(isLeap(1900), False)
testEqual(isLeap(1600), True)
testEqual(isLeap(2056), True)
```

When I tried the code above I got error messages for the years

```
1800 - Test Failed: expected False but got True
1900 - Test Failed: expected False but got True
```

Basically I need my code to say that "the test is true if the year is divisible by four, and, if it's a century year, it's divisible by 400." But when I try:

```
if n % 4 and (n % 100 == 0 and n % 400 == 0):
    return True
else: 
    return False
```

I get three error messages (for the years)

```
1944 - Test Failed: expected True but got False
1956 - Test Failed: expected True but got False
2056 - Test Failed: expected True but got False
```

So it looks like me creating the second condition (divisible by 100 and 400) has canceled out the years that are divisible by 4.

Comment: Should you be comparing `if n % 4` to something?

Comment: `n % 100 == 0 and n % 400 == 0` is redundant; if it's divisible by 400 it will *always* be divisible by 100. Think about your math a little harder.

Comment: By the way, [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621740/how-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year-in-python?rq=1)

Comment: calendar.isleap(year)

Comment: You aren't accounting for the case where it is divisible by 100 but _not_ by 400.

Comment: In your initial code block, the second `if` should be `elif`.  Otherwise you return true for any multiple of 4.

Comment: @applecrusher I needed to create this program without using the calendar function, but still good to know it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
return (n % 100 != 0 and n % 4 == 0) or n % 400 == 0
```

The problem is that you want the year to be divisible cleanly by 4 OR by 400 if it's a century year.

```
>>> [(x % 100 != 0 and x % 4 == 0) or x % 400 == 0 for x in [1944, 1956, 2056, 1800, 1900]]
[True, True, True, False, False]
```

Comment: 1800 and 1900 are not leap years

Comment: Yeah so the key was separating both conditions in the parentheses with an or. Thank you.

Comment: `(x % 100 == 0 and x % 400 == 0)` is redundant.  If `x % 400 == 0` is True, then `x % 100 == 0` must also be true.

Comment: you are correct.  I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments this is already built-in: [calendar.isleap](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/calendar.py#l97)

You can see the [source here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/calendar.py#l97) it's simply:

```
return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Written out long form would look like this (for years > 1600):

```
def isLeapYear(year):
    if year % 4 != 0:
        return False
    elif year % 100 != 0:
        return True
    elif year % 400 != 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a longer, potentially less confusing version:

```
def isLeap(n):
    if n % 4 == 0:
        if n % 100 == 0:
            if n % 400 == 0:
                return True
            return False
        return True
    return False
```