# Python, leap year logic error

Tags: python

```
def is_leap(year): 
    leap = False 
    if(year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or (year%400 == 0 ): 
        print 'Leap Year' 
    else: 
        return leap
```

What do I need to change in the above code?
1992,2400,2000... it doesn't work for these.
I couldn't find any other logic.

Comment: How doesn't it work ?

Comment: See this SO answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621740/how-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621740/how-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year-in-python)

Comment: were you planning on setting leap to True at any point ?

Comment: You need to indent all the remaining lines in your code

Comment: And `year 400 == 0` is invalid syntax, so make sure you're copying it correctly.

Comment: Even if I output it 'True', it doesnt work for 2000,2400,1992.... problem with the logic ?

Comment: yes, 400==0 was edit error while posting here :/ 
rest everything even the indentation is fine, works for other numbers though

Comment: `year=2400` results in a leap year for me, copy-pasting your if-line and the one below. If it doesn't work for you, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine whether a year is a leap year in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621740/how-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of bugs in your code and looks like you missed operation of %400

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0 ):
        leap = True 
    return leap

print(is_leap(2000)) # for 2.7 just print is_leap(2000)
print(is_leap(1000))
print(is_leap(1992))
print(is_leap(2400))
```

output

```
True
False
True
True
```

Comment: You can simplify this even further by doing: `def is_leap(year): return bool((year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0 ))`

Comment: Thanks a ton, it worked 
seems like the problem was I just printed True....

Comment: @AChampion Thanks for correcting it

Answer (score 1):

Your function is called `is_leap`. This does not suggest anything to do with `print`ing. So don't `print` inside your *function!*

```
def is_leap(year): 
    return year % 4 == 0
```

should be enough.

**EDIT:** I looked up the precise definition on Wikipedia:

> Every year that is exactly divisible by four is a leap year, except for years that are exactly divisible by 100, but these centurial years are leap years if they are exactly divisible by 400.

Our function would then be:

```
def is_leap(year): 
    return year % 4 == 0 and not (year % 100 == 0) or year % 400 == 0
```