# Python how to check if it is a leap year with ==int

Tags: python-3.x, int, leap-year

```
 def leapyear(year):
if year/400 == int :
    return False
if year/100 == int :
    return False
if year/4 == int :
    return True
```

hello I would like to know why my code doesn't work with it == to int because essentially its the same thing as using modulo and == to 0 this is just a question that came to me.

```
def check(n): if n > 200: return "large" 
x = n/2 if x !=int: return "odd" 
elif x==0 and n< 100: return "small" 
elif x==0 and n>100: return "medium"
```

also how come the int works here

Comment: `int` is an object type, where `0` is a value of int type

Comment: The leap year function is already available as `calendar.isleap(y)`.  See [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622584/634824).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `int` is a `type`. If you try to compare a number to a type of object, which is what you are doing when you write `if year/400 == int :`, it will always return `False`, because these can never be the same.

A better way to check if `year/400` is an integer would be:

```
if year%400 == 0:
    return False
```

This is saying: 
If the remainder of `year/400` is equal to 0, return `False`, which is what you wanted.

**Some other things are:**

You should use `elif` instead of `if` in most cases. In this one, it doesn't matter, since the `return` statement terminates the execution of the function early, but you should still use it anyways. Otherwise, even when you have your final result, it will go through the rest of the `if` statements.

The other thing isn't related to your code, but your leap year criteria are incorrect. If the year is divisible by 4, then it's a leap year.
Unless the year is divisible by 100, then it's not.
Unless it's divisible by 400, then it is.

Improved code:

```
def leapyear(year):
    if year%400 == 0:
        return True
    elif year%100 == 0:
        return False
    elif year%4 == 0:
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking direct number not its type. You should use....

```
if type(year/400) == int :
       Then here is the conditional block.
elif type(year/100) == int:
       Another Conditional check
elif type(year/4) == int:
       Another conditional block.
```

And you also have a logical error please see the complete code given below.
So your function can be re-written with corrected logic as...

```
def leap_year(year):
    if type(year/400) == int :
       return False
    elif type(year/100) == int:
       return False
    elif type(year/4) == int:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

This is the Complete code.

Comment: Here you are checking that x is a type or not and x is not a type so itv returns True. If you check x == float or any other type it will fail.

Comment: @joey x != int checks if x is a type of int or not.

Answer (score 0):

In Python **int** is considered as Class. You can use **type()** function on a variable to get it's datatype in Python. So, to use your logic you have to rewrite your code as below:

```
def leapyear(year):
    if type(year/400) == int :
        return False
    if type(year/100) == int :
        return False
    if type(year/4) == int :
        return True
```

Note: I have just replicated your code by adding the type() function wherever necessary but it would be suggested to use **if**, **elif** and **else** rather than just if, as it will optimize your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should know output is FLOAT if use '/' .

e.g.

```
2020/400 -> 5.05 
2020/100 -> 20.2
2020/4   -> 505
```

---

You have to change type like using `int()`
e.g.

```
2020/400 -> 5.05  int(2020/400) -> 5
2020/100 -> 20.2  int(2020/100) -> 20
2020/4   -> 505   int(2020/4)   -> 505
```

---

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
time_year = int(sys.argv[1])

def leapyear(year):
    if (year/400) == int(year/400) :
        result = False
    elif (year/100) == int(year/100) :
        result = False
    elif (year/4) == int(year/4) :
        result = True
    else :
        result = 'something worg'
    return result
a=leapyear(time_year)
print a
```

Hope can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
year = int(input("Enter a year: "))

    if (year % 4) == 0:
       if (year % 100) == 0:
           if (year % 400) == 0:
               print("{0} is a leap year".format(year))
           else:
               print("{0} is not a leap year".format(year))
       else:
           print("{0} is a leap year".format(year))
    else:
       print("{0} is not a leap year".format(year))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check a year whether it is leap year or not by returning `True` or `False`
without using any libraries.

```
(lambda year : (year % 400 == 0) or (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0))(2020)
```

Comment: What's the advantage of making this a lambda and not a "real" function?

Comment: sometimes if you need write function for one time use as anonymous or as inline function