# How to find the next leap year since certain year

Tags: python

I need to find the next leap year from user input. A part of the code is working, but if you input "1896", it returns 1900 when it should return 1906. Where does it go wrong?

```
year = int(input("Choose year:"))
year_input = year
while True:
    if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or year % 400 == 0:
        print(f"The next leap year since {year_input} is {year}")
        break
    else:
        year = year + 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine whether a year is a leap year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621740/how-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year)

Comment: you may check this link... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621740/how-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year