# correct my Python leap year code as per below conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, leap-year

- The year can be evenly divided by 4, is a leap year, unless:
- The year can be evenly divided by 100, it is NOT a leap year, unless:
- The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.

**Please correct my code. I'm not looking for alternatives. please use the above conditions**

```py
def is_leap(year):
    nonleap = False
    leap = True
    x = year % 4
    y = year % 100
    z = year % 400
    if(x == 0):
        if((y % 2 != 0) or ((y % 2 == 0) and (z % 2 == 0))):
            return leap
    else:
        return nonleap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine whether a year is a leap year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621740/how-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year)

Comment: Why are you dividing `y` and `z` by 2? They need only be compared to 0 as defined.

Comment: Why are you checking whetther `y` is or is not even? Shouldn't you be checking whether it _equals_ zero? Same with `z`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def is_leap(year):
    x = year % 4
    y = year % 100
    z = year % 400
    if(x == 0):
        if((y != 0) or ((y == 0) and (z == 0))):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're checking whether y and z are divisible by 2.

The solution using your code as base could look like this

```
def is_leap(year):
    nonleap = False
    leap = True
    x = year % 4
    y = year % 100
    z = year % 400
    if x == 0:
        if (y == 0) and not (z == 0):
            return nonleap
        else:
            return leap
    else:
        return nonleap
```

But here's a more elegant pythonic solution
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/write-a-function/forum

```
def is_leap(year):
    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 400 == 0 or year % 100 != 0)
```