# Want python to recognize if an inputted value is an integer

Tags: python

I want the computer to tell me whether a value the user inputted gets divided by 4, it comes out as an integer.  Here is what i have

```
year_input=input("Tell me which year to look up and I will tell you if it was a leap year ")

if ((year_input)/4)== int:
    print("Yep, itś a leap year")
else:
    print("Nope, its not a leap year")
```

Comment: There are approaches to solving the leap year problem in Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621740/how-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year). You need to take the modulus.

Comment: use modulo, but this has already been asked

Comment: It's not that simple to determine leap years.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine whether a year is a leap year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621740/how-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year)

Comment: Sloppy Solution to the Problem:         ```  ```year_input=int(input("Tell me which year to look up and I will tell you if it was a leap year "))

if year_input in [1700, 1800,1900]:
    print('No, thatś not a leap year.')
elif (year_input % 4) == 0:
    print('Yep, its a leap year')
else:
    print('Nope, its not a leap year')   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use modulo (%) operation, it returns the remainder of a division. if it is 0, then your year_input is an integer

```
if (year_input % 4) == 0:
    print("Yep, itś a leap year")
else:
    print("Nope, its not a leap year")
```

Note that this is not enough to determine if the year is a leap year. check out the comment by costaparas.

Comment: Right, I was aware of the formula rules for a leap year and was getting to that next...Thank you for clarifying what the modulo(%) is (Sorry, I´m still very new to all this)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your issue is with the whole leap year problem or if you just want to check if a variable is an int, so since everyone else just taught you how to use % to solve it, I'll answer the other question.

You can use `isinstance` to check if a variable is an instance of a class (in python, EVERYTHING is a class). So, if you had something like this:

```
if isinstance(year_input/4, int): # True
    print("its an int")
else:
    print("thats not an int")
```