# Leap year Python program

Tags: python, leap-year

So, I'm learning Python and I tried to come out with a code for the leap year creating a diagram in order to know my options. I think something might be wrong with it, I just can't figure out what it is. My code follows:

```py
year = int(input("Which year do you want to check?: "))
if year % 4 == 0:
  if year % 100 != 0:
    if year % 400 == 0:
      print("Leap year")
  else:
    print("Not leap")  
else:
 print("Not leap")
```

Comment: What's wrong with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please point out what you think is wrong with your code.  Please include the sample inputs and your outputs (both expected, and actual)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine whether a year is a leap year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621740/how-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year)

Comment: What makes you think something might be wrong with it?

Comment: try adding  `print(year%4,year%100,year%400)` just after you get the input from the user, and see what it's doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (year % 4) == 0:
   if (year % 100) == 0:
       if (year % 400) == 0:
           print("Leap year")
       else:
           print("Not a Leap year")
   else:
       print("Leap year")
else:
   print("Not a Leap year")
```

This should work as your initial condition for Leap Year seems to be wrong.

Comment: Read the algorithm e.g. on Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm

Comment: @Tibebes.M The condition is if the year is division by 4 and 100 and 400 then it's a leap year if the year is divisible by 4 and 100 but not 400 then it's not a leap year, if the year is divisible by 4 and not by 100 then it's a leap year, and if it's not divisible by 4 then again it's not a leap year.

Comment: The code snippet that I have provided matches the algorithm that you have shared @Tibebes.M

Comment: @NupurThakur my bad, it's correct. I was the one wrong whilst evaluating your code.