# local variable referenced before assignment, I can't figure out why this is popping out

Tags: python, python-3.x

These are the instructions:
In the Gregorian calendar, three conditions are used to identify leap years:

The year can be evenly divided by 4, is a leap year, unless:
The year can be evenly divided by 100, it is NOT a leap year, unless:
The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.

So I'm writing this code, which needs to be given a year and if the year is a multiple of 4 and 400 it is a leap year. If it is a multiple of 100 it is not:

```
def is_leap(year):
    k = 400 % year
    m = 4 % year
    p = 100 % year
    if m == 0:
        if p == 0:
            if k == 0:
                leap = True
            else:
                leap = False
    return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

And this is the error message:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'leap' referenced before assignment

I can't figure out why isn't working, leap isn't being used anywhere except for inside the loop

Comment: There are no loops here. Also think: what will `leap` be if `m == 0` or `k == 0` are false?

Comment: You are returning `leap` from the function. Think what will happen if `m = 1`

Comment: If either of the first two `if` statements are false, `leap` is never assigned.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Also, your logic is wrong.  2024 will be a leap year, but that is not a multiple of 100 nor 400, so your  code will give the wrong answer.

Comment: The logic is also wrong because you're doing `400 % year` instead of `year % 400`, and so on.

Comment: Basically the code is equivalent to: `k = 400 ; m = 4 ; p = 100` (for all years after 400 A.D)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine whether a year is a leap year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621740/how-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year)

Comment: You tried to edit my post, but second method works, as the first one https://repl.it/@azro352/PrudentDarkblueCodeview#main.py

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define leap so that it exists when the execution doesn't make it to your innermost block.

```py
def is_leap(year):
    k = 400 % year
    m = 4 % year
    p = 100 % year
    leap = False
    if m == 0:
        if p == 0:
            if k == 0:
                leap = True
    return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

Edit:

As others have correctly pointed out there are are some other problems with the code. In my experience date logic is much trickier than one would expect so instead of trying to roll your own I'd recommend using this:

```py
import calendar
calendar.isleap(year)
```

[Calendar documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#module-calendar)

Comment: Can also be just `if m == 0 and p == 0 and k == 0: leap = True`...

Comment: Yes, there are a few ways to do this but I didn't want to add style comments which are a bit outside the scope of the question.

Comment: In this case, Tomeriko style comment is warranted since the posted code three levels of nesting is overly complicated.

Comment: Ok. I didn't say the comment was not correct or not warranted, though. This question was likely posted by someone new to coding so it's better to not create overly complicated answers for someone still working on mastering the basics.

Comment: That code is still totally wrong about getting a leap year

Answer (score 0):

If `m` or `p` is not equal to 0 then you are returning variable that was not initialized.
You can set `leap=False` before first `if`, and completely delete `else` statement, and code will work as you probably want to.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `leap` variable before assigning it any value. That is what the problem is in my opinion. This is how the code should be

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    k = 400 % year
    m = 4 % year
    p = 100 % year
    leap = False
    if m == 0:
        if p == 0:
            if k == 0:
                leap = True
            else:
                leap = False
    return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

Comment: Note that the `else` is not necessary. Then, this is the same as gph's answer...

Comment: Yep. ```else``` is not actually necessary in this case

Answer (score 0):

There is many mistakes in your code

- `400 % year` should be `year % 400`, same for `4` and `100`
- you may defined `leap` before the `if`, for the case you're not entering the `if` and so not defining it later

More important your definition of *leap year* is wrong, your algorithm is wrong about it

```
def is_leap(year):
    m = year % 4
    p = year % 100
    k = year % 400
    leap = False
    if m == 0:  # should be multiple of 4
        leap = True
        if p == 0:  # exception if multiple of 100 : no leap
            leap = False
            if k == 0:  # exception if multiple of 400 : leap
                leap = True
    return leap
```

If you re-order the condition, you can avoid nesting them

```
def leapyr(n):
    if n % 400 == 0:
        return True
    if n % 100 == 0:
        return False
    if n % 4 == 0:
        return True
    return False
```