# Difficulty defining leap year with function, receiving error as output every time

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am supposed to define leap year as a function. My program must define and call the following function. The function should return true if the input year is a leap year and false otherwise. This is my code, what's throwing me off mainly is the `if __name__ == '__main__'`: , but I am required to have it for my zybooks.

What could be the cause of this? The output I'm receiving is:

```
File "main.py", line 11
if is_leap
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My code:

```
def is_leap_year(user_year)

    def is_leap(year):
        leap = year % 4 == 0 and (year % 400 == 0 or year % 100 != 0)
        return leap
        
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        year = int(input())
        if is_leap
            print(year,"is a leap year.")
        else
            print(year,"is not a leap year.")
```

Comment: You are missing the required colons on your `if` and `else` lines, and you aren't actually calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

You must include the parameter in your call. Also you are missing the colon in the conditional.

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = year % 4 == 0 and (year % 400 == 0 or year % 100 != 0)
    return leap
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    year = int(input())
    if is_leap(year ): # <------ here, added year, call() and colon: 
        print(year,"is a leap year.")
    else: # <------- here, added colon
        print(year,"is not a leap year.")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it gave me back at least 1 correct output this time. However its still failing for some.  ( 1: Compare output
2 / 2
Input
1712
Your output
1712 is a leap year.)
(2: Unit test
0 / 2
is_leap_year(1913)
test_passed function missing)
(3: Unit test
0 / 3
is_leap_year(1600)
test_passed function missing)
(4: Unit test
0 / 3
is_leap_year(1900)
test_passed function missing) Do you know why the other 3 are failing?

Comment: Its hard to tell without looking at the tests, I can assure you that the function output is correct. You can test it using the built in calendar. You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622584 to see how to use it, and check that the answers match. For example 1900 was not a leap year: the function returns false as you expect. Maybe a formatting thing?

Comment: Tried looking at that link you sent, tried some different things from there and I still cant get more than the first test to pass. For all of the failed it says function missing. Which doesn't make sense because the first one passes meaning that when it is a leap year it passes, and if we use else that should receive the other outputs. Should I edit the question above to show the full question to see if maybe theres something I missed in the question?

Comment: I think if you can access and post the tests to see them. For me it doesn't make sense either.

Comment: @Peter you can send the link to the problem. maybe then we can see the test cases

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of my iterations for the same lab.

```
import calendar

def is_leap_year(user_year):

    return calendar.isleap(user_year)

# def is_leap_year(user_year):
#     if user_year % 4 == 0 and (user_year % 100 != 0 or user_year % 400 
#       == 0): #formating went strange in the post
#         return True
#     else:
#         return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_year = int(input())
    if is_leap_year(user_year) is True:
        print('{} is a leap 
year.'.format(user_year))
    else:
        print('{} is not a leap 
year.'.format(user_year))
```

Comment: Your answer is practical to use `calendar` standard library for products, and `calendar.isleap()` function doesn't have to be wrapped by another function, either.

Comment: Agreed. But the requirements of the assignment state "Your program must define and call the following function. The function should return True if the input year is a leap year or False otherwise.
def is_leap_year(user_year)" That is the only reason I put the calendar module into a defined function.

Answer (score -1):

## you need a ":" after the condition of a if statement

```
def is_leap_year(user_year)

def is_leap(year):
    leap = year % 4 == 0 and (year % 400 == 0 or year % 100 != 0)
    return leap
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    year = int(input())
    if is_leap(year):
        print(year,"is a leap year.")
    else:
        print(year,"is not a leap year.")
```