# Zybooks Leap year Python function

Tags: python

6.23 LAB: Leap year - functions

A common year in the modern Gregorian Calendar consists of 365 days. In reality, Earth takes longer to rotate around the sun. To account for the difference in time, every 4 years, a leap year takes place. A leap year is when a year has 366 days: An extra day, February 29th. The requirements for a given year to be a leap year are:

1. The year must be divisible by 4
2. If the year is a century year (1700, 1800, etc.), the year must be evenly divisible by 400

Some example leap years are 1600, 1712, and 2016.

Write a program that takes in a year and determines the number of days in February for that year.

Ex: If the input is:

1712
the output is:

1712 has 29 days in February.
Ex: If the input is:

1913
the output is:

1913 has 28 days in February.
Your program must define and call the following function. The function should return the number of days in February for the input year.
def days_in_feb(user_year)

Hey guys im having trouble with this problem. I am receiving partial credit for this problem, but im struggling with the last part

2: Unit test
0 / 2
days_in_feb(1913)

Your output
days_in_feb(1913) incorrectly returned False

3: Unit test
0 / 3
days_in_feb(1600)

Your output
days_in_feb(1600) incorrectly returned True

4: Unit test
0 / 3
days_in_feb(1900)

Your output
days_in_feb(1900) incorrectly returned False

This is what i currently have done.

def days_in_feb(year):
leap = year % 4 == 0 and (year % 400 == 0 or year % 100 != 0)
return leap

if **name** == '**main**':
year = int(input())
if days_in_feb(year):

```
    print(year,"has 29 days in February.")
else:
    print(year,"has 28 days in February.")
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine whether a year is a leap year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621740/how-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year)

Comment: thats only half of the problem, the other part would be determining if the leap year month has 28 or 29 days as well.

Comment: February has 29 days if and only if it's a leap year. That's the defintion.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little mixed up with your question, format issue, I assume that's why you don't get an answer yet. Since I was also going over Zybooks therefore I just went over this question. Maybe I can show you mine.

```
def days_in_feb(user_year): 
    if user_year % 4 == 0 and user_year % 100 != 0: #Condition to check regular leap years 
        return 29
    elif user_year % 400 == 0:                      #Condition to check XX00s
        return 29
    else:                                           #Condition for non-leap years
        return 28

if __name__ == '__main__':
    year = int(input())
    day = days_in_feb(int(year))
    print(f'{year} has {day} days in February.')
```