# Python - Basic Leap year function problem (Novice)

Tags: python, algorithm

So basically my problem is, I have a list from 2020 to 2030 and my program said every year is a leap year.

My variables are:

```
yearList = [2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029, 2030]
monthList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
daysOfMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31


    def create_calendar(yearList: list, monthList: list, daysOfMonth: list, numbOfShootingStars: int):
    calendar = {}
    for year in yearList:
        # Create year
        calendar[year] = {}
        for month in monthList:
            # If the list don't have 12 months, it won't loop through all months
            if month == 12 and month + 1 == 1: break;
            else:
                # Create monthly data
                calendar[year][month] = {}
                # If February is a leap year, it will have 29 days instead of 28
                if month == 2 and year % 4 == 0:
                        daysOfMonth[month - 1] = 29

                # Create the days and daily data
                for day in range(1, daysOfMonth[monthList.index(month)] + 1):
                    calendar[year][month][day] = numbOfShootingStars

    return calendar
```

Thank you for your help!

- 1 question, is it possible to use a list like this for this method?

  ```
    monthList = [
        {1, 'January'},
        {2, 'February'},
        {3, 'March'},
        {4, 'April'},
        {5, 'May'},
        {6, 'June'},
        {7, 'July'},
        {8, 'August'},
        {9, 'September'},
        {10, 'October'},
        {11, 'November'},
        {12, 'December'}]
  ```

Then how should I modify my code because I couldn't get it work :(

Comment: That is not how you determine leap years. For that you only need the year and a very little math, you do not care about months, you do not care about days.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine whether a year is a leap year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621740/how-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year)

Comment: `month == 12 and month + 1 == 1` can **NEVER** be true. The first part is only true for 12 which makes the second part 13 == 1.

Comment: check the logic of your code, you have things that make no sense: eg: `if month == 12 and month + 1 == 1` will never be true, because month+1 will always be 13. if you break (no need of ;) then you don't need an else. then you are using month as an index in some places, but when you iterate monthList month is the actual content and not an index.  Check your code with a debugger line by line and you will see the problems

Comment: A year is *leap* one if and only if it's divisible by `400` or it's divisible by `4` but not by `100`. In your case (years from 2020 to 2030) the rule can be simplified into "year is leap one if it's divisible by `4`"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I solved it, the problem was, I changed to value in the daysOfMonth list at February to 29 and then it stays like that. With this if - else I changed back to it's original state when it is not a leap year.

```
# If February is a leap year, it will have 29 days instead of 28
                if month == 2 and year % 4 == 0:
                    daysOfMonth[month - 1] = 29
                else:
                    daysOfMonth[month - 1] = 28
```