# Python: To check whether a given year is a leap year or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I wanted to create a python program with user defined function which should read a year entered by user and return True/False by checking whether the entered year is a leap year or not.

This is what I tried

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    if(year%4==0):
        if(year%100!=0):
            if(year%400==0):
                leap= True
            else:
                leap= False
        else:
            leap= False
                
    else:
        leap= False
    
    return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

And I am not getting the desired output.

I tried this code with following two inputs

```
2024
```

Output was

```
False
```

And

```
2023
```

Output was

```
False
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Look at the block diagram of leap year algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm - check which branch is different. Write a few test cases if that helps you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine whether a year is a leap year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621740/how-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's step through your code for 2024:

- `year%4==0` is True, so we enter the if block
- `year%100!=0` is also True, so we enter the if block again.

And now you check for `year%400==0`. Um, why? 2024 isn't a century, so it can never be a multiple of 400. So your logic is broken here. 2024 is divisible by 4 and not divisible by 100. At this point we can simply return True!

Where we need to check for divisibility by 400 is in the next case (where `year%100!=0` is False).

If we take all of this, we get this code:

```
def is_leap(year):
    if(year%4==0):
        if(year%100!=0):
            return True
        else:
            if(year%400==0):
                return True
            else:
                return False
    else:
        return False
```

(note how I got rid of the completely unnecessary variable.)

Comment: I think `(year%4 == 0 and year%100 != 0) or (year%400 == 0)` is equivalent

Comment: @Lesiak It is - but probably less readable for a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

Handling the exceptions first yields clearer code.

```
def is_leap(year):
    if year % 400 == 0:
        return True  # an exception to the century rule
    if year % 100 == 0:
        return False  # centuries aren't leap years
    return year % 4 == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

By nesting the if/else, you act as an AND while you would need an OR.

Best is to refactor your code:

```
def is_leap(year):
    if (year%4==0) and (year%100!=0) or (year%400==0):
        return True
    return False
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
def is_leap(year):
    return (year%4==0) and (year%100!=0) or (year%400==0)
```

Tests:

```
assert not is_leap(1700)
assert not is_leap(1800)
assert not is_leap(1900)
assert not is_leap(2023)
assert is_leap(1600)
assert is_leap(2000)
```

Comment: So 2023 is a leap year?

Comment: @Sören there was a mistake ;)

Comment: Still wrong - 2000

Comment: Please, don't try to be the [fastest gun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/10/06/solving-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem/).

Comment: @mozway Your answer is also fine but the code should also follow Gregorian Calendar  also.

Comment: @AnsuSinha I wouldn't call broken code fine.

Comment: @Sören was busy IRL, I couldn't double check the logic, but the original reason for the failure was valid (OP was using all AND). The current code works